# Is there a better way to perform multiple output with Dash by Plotly?

Tags: python, frameworks, plotly-dash

As we can see in [Interactivity part of Getting started](https://plot.ly/dash/getting-started-part-2#interactivity), one callback function can accept multiple inputs but always has single output.

Assume that we have two blocks separately that must be updated after input change. Of course, the simplest way is to make two callbacks with same input for each of the blocks. The problem is that request performs twice while one is enough to get all data.

```
@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('element_1', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('filter', 'value')])
def callback_element_1(filter):
    return get_data(filter).el1

@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('element_2', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('filter', 'value')])
def callback_element_2(filter):
    return get_data(filter).el2
```

Solution I find is to wrap these elements in single block and re-render it completely with a single request. But in this case all static content in the wrapper will be refreshed too, especially if initial elements are far from each other in DOM.

```
@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('wrapper', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('filter', 'value')])
def callback_element_wrapper(filter):
    data = get_data(filter)
    return html.Div(
        children=[
            data.el1,
            # more static content
            data.el2,
        ]
    )
```

So maybe there are more elegant way to output in two or more elements with a single request?

Comment: Maybe this is something that you can do by setting `app.layout` to a function, so you can serve a dynamic layout.

Have a look at the "Updates on Page Load" in the [live-updates](https://plot.ly/dash/live-updates) section of the documentation.

Comment: @jackdbd, thank you. Not exactly what I need, but very useful

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Now, Plotly Dash supporting multiple outputs in single event. This is with latest version of dash==0.38.0rc1

```
@app.callback(
    [
        Output('output1', 'children'), 
        Output('output2', 'children')
    ],
    [
        Input('output-btn', 'n_clicks'),
        State('output-btn', 'n_clicks_timestamp')
    ]
)
def on_click(n_clicks, n_clicks_timestamp):
    if n_clicks is None:
        raise PreventUpdate

    return n_clicks, n_clicks_timestamp
```

[Git Sample](https://github.com/plotly/dash/pull/436)

Answer (score 7):

Based on [this](https://plot.ly/dash/sharing-data-between-callbacks),
there is a way.

What you can do is to update a hidden "Signal Element" (this can be a text input for example), which in turn, updates the two main elements.

Run the `get_data(filter)` once, and store the result in a global variable. Then instead of updating `element_1` and `element_2`, 
update that signal element.

```
result = []

@app.callback(
dash.dependencies.Output('signal', 'value'),
[dash.dependencies.Input('filter', 'value')])
def callback_signal(filter):
    global result
    result = get_data(filter)
    return filter

@app.callback(
dash.dependencies.Output('element_1', 'children'),
[dash.dependencies.Input('signal', 'value')])
def callback_element_1(filter):
    return result.el1


@app.callback(
dash.dependencies.Output('element_2', 'children'),
[dash.dependencies.Input('signal', 'value')])
def callback_element_2(filter):
    return result.el2
```

In my case, I was using Dash in a single user environment, and using the global variable was not an issue. In case you have multiple users who will be running the app at the same time, the alternatives are available, and you can find them in the same link.

Comment: Great, thank you, I find the alternative way to share it at the page you referred to. But for me it looks like your example is unclear. If you decided to share result in a global variable, there is no need to create hidden div. Just change input in 2nd and 3rd callbacks and completely remove the first. Then check if `result` is calculated, if it's not - call get_data.

Comment: I think that if update the post with approach from "Example 2 - Computing Aggregations Upfront", this should be an accepted answer for a single-session storing. And to share the result across application we can use caching (I've done this with redis)

Comment: That's right, we can check for the change in the global variable, but then it would call the `get_data` twice if it hasn't changed, which I need to avoid in my case. If that's not the issue, yeah, you're right and we can remove that.

Comment: I meant that if initial value of `result` is, for example, `None`, it would compare the variable with `None` and call the `get_data` if it is. Otherwise it would return existing `result` value

Answer (score 2):

What if you can compose the action listeners in an outer function? using Oleh's example

```
def setup_action_callbacks(app):
    result = []

    @app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('signal', 'value'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('filter', 'value')])
    def callback_signal(filter):
        result = get_data(filter)
        return filter

    @app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('element_1', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('signal', 'value')])
    def callback_element_1(filter):
        return result.el1


    @app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('element_2', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('signal', 'value')])
    def callback_element_2(filter):
        return result.el2
```

Such that:

```
def get_app_layout(app):
    setup_action_callbacks(app)
    return html.Div()

app = DjangoDash(name="a_nice_name", app_name="a_nice_app_name")
app.layout = get_app_layout(app)
```

Answer (score 2):

Multi output callbacks support was merged in Dash (2019/03/01).

- See GitHub pull-request: [Multi output callbacks support](https://github.com/plotly/dash/pull/436)
- See announcement: [Multiple outputs in Dash - Now Available!](https://community.plot.ly/t/multiple-outputs-in-dash-now-available/19437)