# Include multiple inputs in a callback

Tags: python, plotly-dash

So, I'm trying to create this form using dash. I want to read all the inputs from this form and throw it into a dataframe. I was able to reference a single input using the callback but I'm unable to reference multiple inputs to be returned using the callback. I'm very new to this.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate

app.config.external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

# build your Dash app
app.layout = html.Div(
[
    html.H2('Form'),
    html.B("Reciever's Name:"),
    html.Br(),
    dcc.Input(id='input-1-state', type='text', placeholder='Enter Name', style={'color':'blue','font-family':'verdana'}),
    html.Br(),
    html.Br(),
    html.B("Reciever's Email:"),
    html.Br(),
    dcc.Input(id='input-2-state', type='email', placeholder='Enter email', style={'color':'blue','font-family':'verdana'}),
    html.Br(),
    html.Br(),
    html.B("Sender's Name:"),
    html.Br(),
    dcc.Input(id='input-3-state', type='text', placeholder='Enter name', style={'color':'red','font-family':'verdana'}),
    html.Br(),
    html.Br(),
    html.B("Sender's Email:"),
    html.Br(),
    dcc.Input(id='input-4-state', type='email', placeholder='Enter email', style={'color':'red','font-family':'verdana'}),
    html.Br(),
    html.Br(),
    html.B("Date:"),
    html.Br(),
    dcc.Input(id='input-5-state', type='date', placeholder='', style={'color':'red','font-family':'verdana'}),
    html.Br(),
    html.Br(),
    html.B("Location:"),
    dcc.Dropdown(['NYC', 'MTL', 'SF'], searchable=True, id='dropdown'),
    html.Br(),
    html.Br(),
    html.B("Select list of values she/he/they demonstrated"),
    html.Br(),
    html.Br(),
    dcc.Checklist(options=[
       {'label': 'New York City', 'value': 'NYC'},
       {'label': 'Montreal', 'value': 'MTL'},
       {'label': 'San Francisco', 'value': 'SF'}]),
    html.Br(),
    html.B("Tell us a little about xyz:"),
    html.Br(),
    dcc.Input(id='input-6-state', type='text', placeholder='Built a very useful dashboard for the sales team', style={'color':'blue','font-family':'verdana','width':'100%', 'height':'flex'}),
    html.Br(),
    html.Br(),
    
    
    html.Button(id='submit-val', n_clicks=0, children='Submit'),
    html.Br(),
    html.Br(),
    html.Div(id='output-container-button',children='Enter a value and press submit')
    
])

@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('output-container-button','children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('input-1-state','value'),
    dash.dependencies.Input('input-2-state','value')]
)

def update_output(value1,value2):
    return "Reciever's Name: {} and Reciveers email: {}".format(value,value)
```

Comment: Try looking at [Is there a better way to perform multiple output with Dash by Plotly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45837031/is-there-a-better-way-to-perform-multiple-output-with-dash-by-plotly?adlt=strict&toWww=1&redig=100B907ABE1649DEA4AB6522F6B0E4CB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error I got when I ran your code was related to `dcc.Input` because it does not accept the argument `type='date'` so instead you can pass `type='text'` and convert it to a datetime object later as necessary.

The following line should work:

```
dcc.Input(id='input-5-state', type='text', placeholder='', style={'color':'red','font-family':'verdana'}),
```

You should be able to store multiple inputs in a DataFrame – I am not sure how you want to use the DataFrame, but I created a `input_data` that is initialized to a dictionary with key-value pairs where the keys are the column names and the values are lists that can be appended to. Something like the following:

```
input_data = {
    "receiver_name": [],
    "receiver_email": [],
    "sender_name": [],
    "sender_email": [],
    "date": [],
    "info": [],
}
```

Then I modified your callback function `update_output` to append the input data to the values of this dictionary, and created a DataFrame inside the function using `df = pd.DataFrame(input_data)`. I'll leave it up to you to decide how you want to use this DataFrame, but I tested it and it works.

Also one really important thing is that all of the `dcc.Input` components that you're passing to your callback should probably be `State` items, and the `Submit` button should be the only input: this means that the input_data will only be updated whenever you press the submit button (if you instead make all of the text boxes inputs along with the button, then the input_data will update every single time to change any of the text boxes, even if you don't press the button).

```
import dash
import pandas as pd
from dash import dcc, html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.config.external_stylesheets = ["https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css"]

# build your Dash app
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.H2("Form"),
        html.B("Reciever's Name:"),
        html.Br(),
        dcc.Input(
            id="input-1-state",
            type="text",
            placeholder="Enter Name",
            style={"color": "blue", "font-family": "verdana"},
        ),
        html.Br(),
        html.Br(),
        html.B("Reciever's Email:"),
        html.Br(),
        dcc.Input(
            id="input-2-state",
            type="email",
            placeholder="Enter email",
            style={"color": "blue", "font-family": "verdana"},
        ),
        html.Br(),
        html.Br(),
        html.B("Sender's Name:"),
        html.Br(),
        dcc.Input(
            id="input-3-state",
            type="text",
            placeholder="Enter name",
            style={"color": "red", "font-family": "verdana"},
        ),
        html.Br(),
        html.Br(),
        html.B("Sender's Email:"),
        html.Br(),
        dcc.Input(
            id="input-4-state",
            type="email",
            placeholder="Enter email",
            style={"color": "red", "font-family": "verdana"},
        ),
        html.Br(),
        html.Br(),
        html.B("Date:"),
        html.Br(),
        dcc.Input(
            id="input-5-state",
            type="text",
            placeholder="",
            style={"color": "red", "font-family": "verdana"},
        ),
        html.Br(),
        html.Br(),
        html.B("Location:"),
        dcc.Dropdown(["NYC", "MTL", "SF"], searchable=True, id="dropdown"),
        html.Br(),
        html.Br(),
        html.B("Select list of values she/he/they demonstrated"),
        html.Br(),
        html.Br(),
        dcc.Checklist(
            options=[
                {"label": "New York City", "value": "NYC"},
                {"label": "Montreal", "value": "MTL"},
                {"label": "San Francisco", "value": "SF"},
            ]
        ),
        html.Br(),
        html.B("Tell us a little about xyz:"),
        html.Br(),
        dcc.Input(
            id="input-6-state",
            type="text",
            placeholder="Built a very useful dashboard for the sales team",
            style={"color": "blue", "font-family": "verdana", "width": "100%", "height": "flex"},
        ),
        html.Br(),
        html.Br(),
        html.Button(id="submit-val", n_clicks=0, children="Submit"),
        html.Br(),
        html.Br(),
        html.Div(id="output-container-button", children="Enter a value and press submit"),
    ]
)

input_data = {
    "receiver_name": [],
    "receiver_email": [],
    "sender_name": [],
    "sender_email": [],
    "date": [],
    "info": [],
}


@app.callback(
    Output("output-container-button", "children"),
    Input("submit-val", "n_clicks"),
    [
        State("input-1-state", "value"),
        State("input-2-state", "value"),
        State("input-3-state", "value"),
        State("input-4-state", "value"),
        State("input-5-state", "value"),
        State("input-6-state", "value"),
    ],
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def update_output(
    n_clicks,
    value1,
    value2,
    value3,
    value4,
    value5,
    value6,
    input_data=input_data,
):
    input_data["receiver_name"].append(value1)
    input_data["receiver_email"].append(value2)
    input_data["sender_name"].append(value3)
    input_data["sender_email"].append(value4)
    input_data["date"].append(value5)
    input_data["info"].append(value6)
    df = pd.DataFrame(input_data)
    # print(df)
    return "Receiver's Name: {} and Receiver's email: {}".format(value1, value2)


app.run_server(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

Here are some test inputs:

[image]

Here is a print out of the `input_df` that your function updates after I click the submit button:

```
  receiver_name receiver_email sender_name   sender_email        date                      info
0           foo  foo@gmail.com         bar  bar@gmail.com  2022-08-28  Here is some sample text
```

And if I press the submit button again, the `input_df` is updated accordingly:

```
  receiver_name receiver_email sender_name   sender_email        date                      info
0           foo  foo@gmail.com         bar  bar@gmail.com  2022-08-28  Here is some sample text
1           foo  foo@gmail.com         bar  bar@gmail.com  2022-08-28  Here is some sample text
```

---